# Program to calculate LCM of K consecutive numbers mod 1000000007 with low complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, prime-factoring

I have to write a program such that for several Queries  of type L,R
i have to output the LCM of numbers from L to R.
where R can max go to M

I have Managed to  write a program of complexity N(Q).M ,
I need to do it in N(Q).Log(M) or N(Q).sqrt(M) .

Here N(Q) denotes no of queries. sqrt denotes square root.

EDIT:  I wrote it using Segmentree , however getting a wrong answer, here powf finds a^b %  P in logn time :
My query code:

```
 long long findfunc(long long ql,long long qr,long long ind)
  {
 if(a >qr || b<ql)
   return 1;
 if(a>=ql && b<=qr)
  { //cout<<"LCM "<<ql<<" to "<<qr<<" "<<val[ind]<<endl; 
   return  val[ind]%mod;
  }
 else
  {
 ll vl= findfunc(ql,qr,2*ind+1);
 ll vr= findfunc(ql,qr,2*ind+2);
 return  ( ((vl*vr)%mod) * powf(gcd(vl,vr),mod-2)  )%mod;
 }  
}
```

Comment: what is the limit for M?

Comment: M can goto 10^5 and N(Q) can goto 10^6

Comment: Try learning `Segment Trees`.

Comment: I already know it , but confused with query operation

Comment: Do you have only get LCM or update item queries ?

Comment: only LCM queries no update queries

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). The idea is to store the least common multiple of `l, l+1, ..., r` in each node representing the interval `[l, r]`.

- **how to build** - you start bottom up and when you have to merge to nodes `[a, b]`, `[b+1, c]` you do the following. Let `lcm([a, b]) = l1` and  `lcm([b+1, c]) = l2` then `lcm([a, c]) = lcm(lcm([a, b]), lcm([b+1, c])) = lcm(l1, l2) = l1*l2 / gcd(l1,l2)`. Since `gcd(l1,l2)` is roughly constant the merge operation is constant.
- **how to query** - if you have the interval `[a, b]` you find the node in the tree such that they represent the ranges `[a, c]` and `[c+1, b]` for some `c`. Then the calculation of `lcm([a, b])` is the same as in the merging step.

Comment: if(a >qr || b<ql)
   return 1;
  if(a>=ql && b<=qr)
   { //cout<<"LCM "<<ql<<" to "<<qr<<" "<<val[ind]<<endl; 
     return  val[ind]%mod;
  }
  else
   {
     ll vl= findfunc(ql,qr,2*ind+1);
     ll vr= findfunc(ql,qr,2*ind+2);
     return  ( ((vl*vr)%mod) * powf(gcd(vl,vr),mod-2)  )%mod;
  }

Comment: getting wrong answer when using mod multiplicative inverse of GCD(l1,l2)

Comment: @smartsn123 I guess you have error in the code? why don't test it with simple cases?

Comment: without mod multiplicative inverse i am gettig fine for small test cases by dividing by gcd(l1,l2),  but using modmulInverse I get Wrong even for gmall test cases. So i Guess Segmentree code is fine , but using modMulInv is messing up.

Comment: Please have a look at above code i have in EDIT and suggest error possible

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for data structure called `Segment Trees`. I won't be providing the code, because that is not what we do here on SO.

This link:

https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/

will be of help to you.

Comment: I know about it , but , confused with merging  two ranges

Comment: @svs has written a nice answer regarding that confusion of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I not a C++ expert, you can take a look to my C# implementation, I believe this is not difficult convert to C++.

```
private const int Mid = 128 * 1024;
private static long mod = 1000000007;
private static long[] t = new long[Mid + Mid];
public static void Initialize(long[] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) t[Mid + i] = a[i];
    for (int i = a.Length; i < Mid; i++) t[Mid + i] = 1;
    for (int i = Mid - 1; i > 0; i--) t[i] = LCM(t[i + i], t[i + i + 1]);
}

public static long GetLcm(int l, int r)
{
    l += Mid;
    r += Mid;
    long ans = 1;
    while (l <= r)
    {
        ans = LCM(ans, t[l]);
        ans = LCM(ans, t[r]);

        l = (l + 1) / 2;
        r = (r - 1) / 2;
    }

    return ans;
}

public static void Update(int i, long v)
{
    i += Mid;
    t[i] = v;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        i = i / 2;
        t[i] = LCM(t[i + i], t[i + i + 1]);
    }
}

private static long GCD(long a, long b)
{
    if (a % b == 0) return b;
    return GCD(b, a % b);
}

private static long LCM(long a, long b)
{
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
    return ((a * b) / GCD(a, b)) % mod;
}
```

you can use it via following code:

```
    long[] m = new long[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    Initialize(m);
    var ans1 = GetLcm(0, 9);
    Update(8, 6);
    var ans2 = GetLcm(0, 9);
```

This is not optimized solution but should works.
As data structure used segment tree.
If you really not need Update operation SparseTable also will be usable here.